# Windows: Find files with permission assignments for specific user

Tags: windows, permissions, file-permissions, windows-server-2008-r2

We have an IIS web application that works when using one application pool ("IIS AppPool\OldPool"), but not another ("IIS AppPool\NewPool"). It seems extremely likely that this is due to missing file permissions.
I have already run SysInternals' Process Monitor to identify some missing permissions (where specific permissions were given to "IIS AppPool\OldPool"), but the problem is not solved.

I would now like to find all files/directories with specific permissions assigned to "IIS AppPool\OldPool".

I don't care about actual or effective permissions etc. - we're probably only talking a handful of files at most and permissions will usually be assigned to groups anyway.

Is there a way to do this with onboard tools or would I have to script this?

Answer (score 2):

Another one of the SysInternals suite of tools, **AccessEnum**, can retrieve the specific permissions set throughout the filesystem:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/accessenum

Once the data has been retrieved, AccessEnum can save that data to a text file which you can search for the user account you are interested in. The output is in tab-delimited format so I would suggest importing it into Excel and using a column filter to show only those entries containing the username you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks! This looks like a good option.